# Linha corta texto no acompanhamento de medalhas

Tags: bug

Costumo usar o site de máquinas diferentes com navegadores diferentes, porém sempre está da mesma forma. A linha que eu imaginava ser um `<hr>`, é um `<span>`, corta o texto da descrição, o que não acontece no SO porquê o texto em inglês é mais curto.

[image: A linha corta o texto]